# How to give path while saving images using PIL in Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble figuring what path definition to give while saving my files - absolute system path or relative path to my static files directory

My minimized photo model -

```
 class Photos(models.Model):
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_photo_storage_path)
```

MY thumbnail model -

```
 class PhotosThumbnails(models.Model):
        photo = models.ForeignKey(Photos)
        dp = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_thumbnail_storage_path)
```

And my view -

```
photo_thumbnail_obj = PhotosThumbnails(photo = photos_object)
size = 40, 40
im = Image.open(str(obj.photo.path))
im.thumbnail(size)
im.save( ?? , 'JPEG')
photo_thumbnail_obj.dp = ??
photo_thumbnail_obj.save()
```

Help Python People, I want to save it using the relative path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always save with an absolute system path.

```
im.save('/var/www/_uploads/myphoto.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Since you're in Django, you may also want to do this:

```
im.save(settings.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + 'myphoto.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: To build on this, I'd suggest to use an absolute path, based on the project's relative path, using `os.path.abspath`.

Comment: Possibly even better would be to do settings.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + 'myphoto.jpg', so we're not hardcoding.

Comment: Consider using settings.STATICFILES_DIR (is a tuple, so index [0] you get the first path). Also settings.MEDIA_URL . This will give you the freedom of access /static/imgs/yours.jpg from Templates.